# (laravel) Error: Method call uses 3 parameters

Tags: laravel, builder

I am trying to retrieve multiple data from a database in laravel query builder. I get an error at "from".

I tried looking on internet, it keeps talking about join, but I don't want a join.

```
$showtitles = DB::table('funny_pictures', 'jokes', 'riddles')
            ->select('title', 'id', 'type')
            ->from('funny_pictures', 'jokes', 'riddles')
            ->where('user_id', $user -> id)
            ->orderBy('created_at')
            ->paginate(6);
        return view('profile', compact('user', 'jokes', 'showtitles'));
```

This is the query, it gives the error at from

It only selects "funny_pictures" not jokes and riddles.

Comment: You have to use join

Comment: You need to add join statements https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this (with join rather than table with 3 tables in it).

```
$showtitles = DB::table('funny_pictures')
                ->join('jokes', 'user_id', $user -> id)
                ->join('riddles', 'user_id', $user -> id)
                ->select('title', 'id', 'type')
                ->from('funny_pictures')
                ->where('user_id', $user -> id)
                ->orderBy('created_at')
                ->paginate(6);

return view('profile', compact('user', 'jokes', 'showtitles'));
```